# My program uses IMDBpy is there a way i can use this program without manually installing IMDBpy before using it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imdbpy

I've written a program on python that I want to give out to my friends but at the moment to use the program you have to install IMDBpy in the terminal using "pip install imdbpy".

Is there anyway I can integrate this command into my program so they can't just launch the program straight away?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could package all of your code it with PyInstaller so your friends can just run it without installing anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can clone [their repository](https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy), and copy the imdb folder in the root of your project. This way, when python will import imdb, python will look for that module in the root of the project and will use the folder you just copied. And because this is the official repo, it will work as intended,